# Ошибка ClassNotFoundException в моем загрузчике классов

Tags: java

Я создал свой загрузчик классов.

```
package ru.sberbank.school.homework8;

import ru.sberbank.school.homework8.plugin.Plugin;

import java.io.*;

public class PluginManager extends ClassLoader {
    private final String pluginRootDirectory;

    public PluginManager(String pluginRootDirectory) {
        this.pluginRootDirectory = pluginRootDirectory;
    }

@Override
public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    if (name.startsWith(pluginRootDirectory)) {
        return findClass(name);
    }
    return super.loadClass(name);
}

public Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    try {
        byte b[] = loadClassData(name + ".class");
        return defineClass(name, b, 0, b.length);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        return super.findClass(name);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return super.findClass(name);
    }
}

// получаем байт-код класса
private byte[] loadClassData(String path) throws IOException {
    try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(path))) {

        // Get the size of the file
        long length = new File(path).length();

        if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            // File is too large
        }

        // Create the byte array to hold the data
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];

        // Read in the bytes
        int offset = 0;
        int numRead;
        while (offset < bytes.length
                && (numRead = is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length - offset)) >= 0) {
            offset += numRead;
        }

        // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
        if (offset < bytes.length) {
            throw new IOException("Could not completely read file " + path);
        }

        return bytes;
    }
}

public Plugin load(String pluginName, String pluginClassName)  {
    String name = pluginRootDirectory + "\\" + pluginName + "\\" + pluginClassName;
    try {
        return (Plugin)loadClass(name).newInstance();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Запускаю код

```
package ru.sberbank.school.homework8;

import ru.sberbank.school.homework8.plugin.Plugin;

import java.io.File;

public class PluginManagerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pluginRootDirectory = "D:\\sbt\\target\\classes\\ru\\sberbank\\school\\homework8";
        PluginManager pluginManager = new PluginManager(pluginRootDirectory);
        Plugin plugin = pluginManager.load("plugin", "PluginImpl");
        if (plugin != null) {
            plugin.doUseful();
        }
    }
}
```

и получаю ошибку

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: D:\sbt\target\classes\ru\sberbank\school\homework8\plugin\PluginImpl
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)
```

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Вы проверяете, что имя класс не начинается с `pluginRootDirectory` и в этом случае делегируете загрузку *Java*-вскому загрузчику. *Java*-вский загрузчик ничего не знает про ваш класс и поэтому падает.

`pluginRootDirectory` содержит:

```
D:\sbt\target\classes\ru\sberbank\school\homework8
```

Очевидно, что имя класса не может так начинаться.

Answer (score 0):

`ClassNotFoundException` возникает, если мы пытаемся загрузить класс во время выполнения и данный класс не доступен для Java. Возможно причина — неправильный `Classpath`. Возможно, что приложение использует совсем другой Classpath. Бывает, что один Classpath перезаписывает другой, смотря как Вы запускаете приложение.
А вообще тем по данному вопросу обсуждалось очень много, загуглите ошибку свою, получите множество ответов на свой вопрос и возможные пути решений. Также посмотрите, как работает загрузчик и его принципы : делегирование, уникальность и т.п.